# Pass list of instances of generic type with different T

Tags: c#, generics

I have such generic class:

```
public class MyGen<T>
{
   public MyGen(T val)
   {
      Val = val;
   }
   public T Val { get; }
}
```

Processor class:

```
public class Proc
{
   public void Do<T>(params MyGen<T>[] arr)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
var proc = new Proc();
proc.Do(new MyGen<int>(5), new MyGen<string>("bla"));
```

**UPD**: solution with base none-generic class and generic derived class. I suppose it's better because there is no boxing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var proc = new Proc();
        proc.Do(new MyGen<int>(55), new MyGen<string>("dsdasd"));

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Proc
{
    public void Do(params MyGenBase[] arr)
    {
        foreach (var it in arr)
        {
            it.Do();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class MyGenBase
{
    public abstract void Do();
}

public class MyGen<T> : MyGenBase
{
    public MyGen(T val)
    {
        Val = val;
    }

    public T Val { get; }

    public override void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Did I miss any disadvantages here? Please comment this approach.

Comment: No, because you have two different types and ony one `T`. You could change the signature of `Do` to take a `params MyGen<object>[] arr` though.

Comment: A way to think about it is think of the generic classes as non generic classes with the name of the generic type, so you have two totally separate classes, one named `MyGen_string` and one named `MyGen_int`, so if generics did not exist how would you make `proc.Do(new MyGen_int(5), new MyGen_string("bla")` work?

Comment: @stuartd Compiler error: Cannot convert from `MyGen<int>` to `MyGen<object>`.

Comment: Well, yes, You would also have to declare your objects as `MyGen<object>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like this. Because `Do` method can't accept different types of `MyGen` class. So, creation a base class might be an option;

```
public class BaseMyGen
{

}

public class MyGen<T> : BaseMyGen
{
    public MyGen(T val)
    {
        Val = val;
    }
    public T Val { get; }
}
public class Proc
{
    public void Do(params BaseMyGen[] arr)
    {
        var myGen1 = arr[0] as MyGen<int>;
        var myGen2 = arr[1] as MyGen<string>;
    }
}
var proc = new Proc();
proc.Do(new MyGen<int>(5), new MyGen<string>("bla"));
```

Comment: I like this approach because here I can avoid boxing and unboxing. But in this case I need to encapsulate all logic related to `Val` property inside generic class.

Comment: This is very fragile code. At least use `OfType<T>()`. If you’re passing instances with a known set of type parameters, declare distinct method parameter collections with those types.

Answer (score 0):

Your example Do statement doesn't take in an array as a parameter, but instead 2 separate parameters.

What about using an array with 2 objects, so that way you can place a 5 and the string "bla" in the array.

```
var proc = new Proc();
var Items = new List<MyGen<object>>();
Items.Add(new MyGen<object>(5));
Items.Add(new MyGen<object>("bla"));
proc.Do(Items.ToArray());
```

Comment: Altought this is valid, it's easier just to do `proc.Do(new MyGen<object>(5), new MyGen<object>("bla"));` also, don't give the list the same name of the class.

Comment: Changed the var name

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem with generics, and there's a classic solution. For example, `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and also implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable`. And this is why.

```
public interface IMyGen
{
    object Val { get; }
}
public class MyGen<T> : IMyGen
{
    public MyGen(T val)
    {
        Val = val;
    }
    public T Val { get; }

    object IMyGen.Val => this.Val;
}
public class Proc
{
    public void Do(params IMyGen[] arr)
    {

    }
}
```

If all the casting due to the explicit interface implementation is too much hassle, you can give the non-generic property a different name:

```
public interface IMyGen
{
    object Value { get; }
}
public class MyGen<T> : IMyGen
{
    public MyGen(T val)
    {
        Val = val;
    }
    public T Val { get; }

    public object Value => Val;
}
public class Proc
{
    public void Do(params IMyGen[] arr)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm not a fan of that approach: A property has one right name. But sometimes you're stuck with it.

Comment: Unfortunately I will face here with boxing-unboxing while working with primitive T.

Comment: @mtkachenko There is no possible way to do this without boxing value types. No possible way. Why is that a problem?

Comment: In previous answer I don't need to put value type to object.

Comment: @mtkachenko I can read. Why do you think that is a problem? Don’t just keep repeating yourself. Tell me why you think it’s a problem. Tell me what assumptions you’re making. What are you *assuming*?

Comment: I have two options: with and without boxing. I prefer the 2nd one. In case of using `IMyGen.Value` I have to cast it back to value type, use `GetType()` instead of `typeof` etc. Is it sensible for you?

Comment: @mtkachenko No. Wrong. In Proc.Do(), if you want to deal with more than one T in the array, you have one option: Boxing. Boxing is all you can possibly have in that method in this language. I am telling you how the .NET team approaches this issue: Boxing. They are better at this than you are, trust me.

Comment: I've added update to my question. Could you comment it?

Comment: I could, but I’ve lost interest.

Comment: It would be better if you try to find it again.

Comment: This is a small subject. I’ve told you what you need to know. Now it’s up to you to understand and apply it.

Comment: You still haven't explained why your approach is better than "generic way".

Comment: If you’re passing a fixed set of known types in a particular order, declare them as distinct parameters of the expected types. I don’t have the time to explain why compile time type checking is a good idea, and I suspect you’d argue about it if I did.